# 2 plus inch gap on garage floor and walls

Tags: concrete, installation, gap

My mom just bought a 4 year old home. The garage has a 2 plus inch gap filled with insulation on the floor and up the walls. Does anyone know why these large gaps are there and unfinished and how best to finish them appropriately so they look better?

[image]

Comment: Is the tape measure on the floor or up a wall? It's hard to tell with no context.

Comment: Sorry. Tape measure is on the floor

Answer (score 1):

The 2" gap is created by the code required foundation insulation. What you see is typical, sad but true. To dress it up you could remove about 1/2" of it by scratching it out, (some may need a little chipping too) and fill it with a [self-leveling caulk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000RUKZSA). The name of the product is self explanatory, use a large caulk gun and squeeze it into the recess you made in the insulation. Do not place too much it will overflow onto the floor, You can always add more, but difficult to clean up if too much is added.